# numpy linspace returning negative numbers for a positive interval

Tags: python, numpy

```
np.linspace(10**3, 10**6, num=5, dtype=np.int16)
```

yelds

```
array([  1000, -11394, -23788,  29354,  16960], dtype=int16)
```

I don't understand the presence of negative numbers in a positive interval.

Can anyone point me to what I'm missing ? (And eventually how can I manage to get linearly spaced numbers over long sequences of integers like those.)

Thanks!

Comment: It's overflowing because you're only using 16 bit integers. You need to increase to `np.int32` or `np.int64`

Comment: what a silly mistake.... thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the reason for this is [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

More specifically, you asked for numbers between 1E3 to 1E6, but `int16` supports values in the range `[-32768, 32767]`. When we try to represent a number like `40000` using `int16`, the value wraps and what we get is `40000-2**16 == -25536`. Large numbers keep "wrapping" until they are small enough to be represented.